# AppleScript: How to filter messages based on find or Smart Mailbox?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to leverage Apple Mail's search capability to quickly get to a list of emails based on content. If I step through with AppleScript and extract each emails content, it takes about 100 times longer:

```
repeat with aMessage in (messages of inbox whose date received ≥ dDate)
    set tContent to content of aMessage as rich text
    if "findtext" is in tContent then
        do stuff
    end if
end repeat
```

How can do one of the following:
1. Use the UI commands to type in a search term and access the selected messages in a script.
2. Use the UI commands to switch to a custom or favorite MailBox and then access the selected messages in a script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to actually do this in Outlook. I switched to Apple Mail and was able to get it to work a little faster using similar code.